# What is the easiest way I can send one contact's phone number to another on my Android?

Tags: contacts, nexus-one, 2.2-froyo, sms

I have to send two contacts in my phone book to another contact, on my Nexus One Android 2.2. How can I do this easiest?

On my old SonyEricsson this function was on a nearby menu, but I can't find it on Android.

I have also tried to copy the phone number when in edit mode of the contacts, but I can not paste it when composing the SMS to my contact. Is there really no way to transfer a contact via SMS or MMS on Android other than writing the numbers down on paper and then write them in the SMS message later as in the stone age?

Comment: Failing the answers below, copy and paste from Contacts app to Messaging app should just work without any problem, I've used it a few times before to copy lines from addresses, emails and that sort of thing into a SMS. Are you sure you long-pressed long enough in the SMS message to get the input menu up with the Paste option on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste from Contacts app to Messaging app should just work without any problem, I've used it a few times before to copy lines from addresses, emails and that sort of thing into an SMS.

Are you sure you long-pressed long enough in the SMS message to get the input menu up with the `Paste` option on it? Or that you copied it properly in the first place? Copying data from a Contact is most easily done by `Edit`ing the Contact, then long-pressing on the field you're interested until the input menu comes up with the `Copy All` option.

Answer (score 1):

On my HTC Evo I can open contacts, then long click on the contact I want, and then choose "Send contact as vCard". This opens another menu that allows me to choose what portions of the contact to send along and how to send, via text, email, bluetooth.

Also you can try the app "Shacts" which allows you to create QR codes of contacts very easily and then share them or scan them right from the screen.

[Update]
Another app to try for older Android releases is QR Contact 1.6.

Comment: Very similar option on my Samsung Galaxy "Send Namecard via -> Messaging" which creates an MMS message with the VCF file attached. Though I do know that on my old HTC Magic running stock Android 1.6 there was no easy way to do this other than copy/paste, so I wonder if we're seeing additions that our manufacturers have added on with their custom GUIs.

Comment: Yup, that is basically the same thing HTC Sense phones do. Pretty nifty feature. On 1.6 you should be able to download an app to convert the contact to a QR code. If the one I mentioned doesn't work, QR Contacts 1.6 should work.